Can I chant OM NAMAH SHIVAY without initiation?
Will it harm me or is it meaningless to chant OM NAMAH SHIVAAY without initiation? If initiation is needed, how to get initiated as I don't have any guru?

Shivaya namah can be chanted without initiation but to chant om i.e, pranava one needs to get initiated

Yes. It can be chanted even without initiation.

The devotee shall approach the brahmin preceptor who knows the
principles, performs Japa, is devoted to meditation and endowed with
virtues. He shall strenuously propitiate him mentally, verbally,
physically and monetarily. He shall possess the purity of piety.(10 to
12)
This mantra is not ineffective even if it is not properly imparted by
the preceptor. It is not ineffective even in the case of persons not
caring for good conduct and who have not purified the six paths.(64)
[Shiva Purana Vāyavīya-saṃhitā (2), Chapter 14]


This is correct. I have seen this verse myself. No diksha is required.

I don't think any initiation is required for chanting,
there is no harm,
it will bring positive vibes only,
you will be set free and will do the next impossible thing.
for starters, along with chanting ॐ नमः शिवाय you can also

Shiv suvarnamala stuti
Shiv stuti
Shiv tandav strotra
Shiv avhan mantra


I) Your first question Will it harm me or is it meaningless to chant OM NAMAH SHIVAAY without initiation?
Since Om Namash Shivāya(ॐ नमश्शिवाय) is a Moola Mantra, that can't be recited without initiation(Mantra Dīksha/मन्त्र दीक्षा) from a competent Guru (the one who has perfected/acquired already the Mantra Siddhi for Sri Shiva Devatha)
II) Your second and final question If initiation is needed, how to get initiated as I don't have any guru?
In order to accomplish Mantra Siddhi(मन्त्र सिद्ध), it is necessary to get initiated known as Mantra Dīksha(मन्त्र दीक्षा) from a competent Guru. However, If you don't have a Guru, then approach the Ādi Guru (आदिगुरु/Universal Guru) Who is Sri Dakshinā Moorthi(श्रीदक्षिणामूर्ति) Himself.

Visit a temple of God Dakshinā Moorthi near by and take permission from Him by offering Misrī (मिश्री/Sugar Candy/Rock Candy/கற்கண்டு) along with Channa pulse (चना दाल/சுண்டல்) and a piece of yellow Vastram (वस्त्रम्/Cloth) of a meter length.
You should begin the initiation (Mantra Dīkshā/मन्त्र दीक्षा) by chanting Dyāna Sloka of Devata (Shiva/शिव) with reverence in front of God Dakshinā Moorthi, which is given below:


ॐ ध्यायेन्नित्यं महेशं रजतगिरिनिभं चारुचन्द्रवतंसं
रत्नाकल्पोज्ज्वलाङ्ग परशुमृगवराभीतिहस्तं प्रसन्नम्।
पद्मासीनं समन्तात् स्तुततममरगणैर्व्याघ्रकृत्तिं वसानं
विश्वाद्यं विश्वरूपं निखिलभयहरं पञ्चवक्त्रं त्रिनेत्रम्॥

Om dhyāyennityaṃ maheśaṃ rajatagirinibhaṃ cārucaṃdrā vataṃsaṃ
ratnākalpojjvalāṃgaṃ paraśumṛgavarābhītihastaṃ prasannam ।
padmāsīnaṃ samaṃtātsthitamamaragaṇairvyāghrakṛttiṃ vasānaṃ |
viśvādyaṃ viśvabījaṃ nikhilabhayaharaṃ paṃcavaktraṃ trinetram ॥



Meaning of Dyāna Sloka: He is lustrous like a mountain of silver with the beautifully shining moon on his forehead. He is adorned with gems and carries in each of his four hands, a battle-axe [परशु/மழு], a deer [மான்] and the gestures of granting boons [வரம்] and dispelling fear [அபயம்]. He is gracious and seated on a lotus, raimented with a tiger-skin [புலித்தோல்] and surrounded by all Devas who are singing his praise. He is the source of universe. His form is the universe. He dispels all fears. He has five faces [பஞ்சமுகம்] with three eyes [முக்கண்] in each.

Perform Japa(जप/Repetition) of Moola Mantra(मूल मन्त्र) for 108 times in front of Him with complete focus. The Panchāksharī (पञ्चाक्षरि/Five syllabled Mantra) Shiva Moola Mantra(शिव मूल मन्त्र) is:



ॐ नमश्शिवाय।
Om Namash Shivāya।

1. Who is Rishi(ऋषि/Seer/मंत्र द्रष्टा/Who discovered Mantra) : Vāmadeva Rishi (वामदेव ऋषि).
2. What is Chandas(छन्दस्/Metrical Structure of Mantra): Pankti Chandas(पंक्ति छन्दस्).
3. Who is Devatha(देवता): Īsvara Devatha (ईश्वर देवता).



After completing this initiation (Dīkshā/दीक्षा), you should strongly believe that Lord Sri Dakshinā Moorthi has blessed you with Mantra Dīksha for the endeavour you have undertaken. Keep unwavering faith in the Devatha you have chosen (in your case, it is Īsvara/ईश्वर) and never switch Devatha in between. Never discuss about your endeavour or upāsana Devatha with anybody and just maintain the secrecy all along.

I) How can I attain Siddhi by "Shiva Moola Mantra"?

This Devatha Upasana should be performed everyday or according to a solid time table. Based on your focus, dedication and perseverance you will taste success (Devatha Vasyam/देवता वश्यम्). This may take few weeks or few years, all in your hands particularly upon your Prārabdha Karma(प्रारब्ध कर्म) in this birth.

The Purashcharana (पुरश्चरण) generally will have five angas (अङ्ग/Parts) but the Purashcharana of Shiva Tantra (शिव तन्त्र) consists of only the following two angas(अङ्ग/Parts):

Beware-1: Rishiyādhi Nyāsa (ऋष्यादिन्यास), Kara Nyāsa (करन्यास) and Hridiyādhi-Shadanga Nyāsa (हृदयादिषडङ्गन्यास) for Shiva Tantra have been given at the bottom [Refer Appendix]. These Nyāsa should be carried out before beginning of Japa (जप).
i) Japa(जप): With concentrated mind, perform Twenty Four Lakh (24,00,000) moola mantra Japas for Shiva Tantra Upāsana (शिव तन्त्र उपासना).
ii) Havana(हवन): Throw 24,000 Āhutis (आहुति/oblation) of Pāyasa (पायस/Hindi: Kheer-खीर/பாயாசம்) by uttering mantra ॐ नमश्शिवाय स्वाहा in the fire of Havana Kunda.
Note: Havana Mantra for Sri Shiva Tantra is nothing but the Moola Mantra appended with svāhā.

Beware-2: Before beginning of any karma (कर्मन्/Event), such as Japa or Puja, Sankalpa (सङ्कल्प/சங்கல்பம்) should be taken for the outcome to be sathkārya (सत्कार्य/Efficacious).
The Mamopātta Sankalpa Mantra (ममोपात्त सङ्कल्पं मन्त्र/மமோபாத்த சங்கல்ப மந்திரம்) for Īsvara Japa is as follows:

ममोपात्त समस्त दुरितक्षय द्वारा श्रीपरमॆश्वर प्रीत्यर्थं
ईश्वर देवता महा मन्त्र जपम् अहम् करिष्ये॥
Or Vaishnava followers:
ममोपात्त समस्त दुरितक्षय द्वारा श्रीमन्नारायण प्रीत्यर्थं
ईश्वर देवता महा मन्त्र जपम् अहम् करिष्ये॥

Mamopātta samastha durithakshaya dwāra Sri Parameshwara preethyartham
Īsvara devatha mahā mantra japam aham karishye॥
Or Vaishnava followers:
Mamopātta samastha durithakshaya dwāra Srimannārāyana preethyartham
Īsvara devatha mahā mantra japam aham karishye॥

Note: Produce Sankalpa Mudra while chanting the above Mamopātta Mantra.

II) Sri Shiva Yantra(शिव यन्त्र): An image of Sri Shiva Devatha as described in Dyāna sloka and a typical Sri Shiva Yantra (श्रीशिव यन्त्र) are given below:

III) Indication of fructification of the Mantra: The feeling of delight and satisfaction, hearing the sound of wardrums, percussion instruments and songs seeing the Gandharvas (गन्धर्व/Heavenly Choristers) seeing one’s own brilliance similar to that of the Sun, conquest over sleep and hunger, feeling pf pleasure in japa(जप), becoming healthy and grave, absence of anger and greed - If the Sādaka (सादक/Aspirant) knowing the mantras, observe these symptoms, he should conclude that the Upāsana Devathā is pleased and the fructification of the Mantra is imminent.
Appendix:
Rishiyādhi Nyāsa, Kara Nyāsa and Hridiyadhi Nyāsa (aka Shadanga Nyāsa) should be performed for Sri Shiva Tantra before beginning of purascharana (पुरस्चरण).
What is Nyāsam (न्यास)? Nyāsa (Deposit/Setting Down) is a Tantric ritual in Hinduism which involves touching various parts of the body while chanting specific portions of a mantra. This imposition of mantras upon the body is considered as the assigning or locating of divinity inside one's own body.

Therefore, the purpose of Nyāsa is to make the body of the Sadhaka more divine before proceeding to purascharanam (पुरस्चरण).

I) Rishiyādhi Nyāsa (ऋष्यादिन्यास) for Sri Shiva Tantra:

ॐ वामदेवर्षये नमः शिरसि। - by uttering this mantra, touch head.
ॐ पंक्तिच्छन्दसे नमो मुखे। - by uttering this mantra, touch face.
ॐ ईश्वर देवतायै नमो हृदि। - by uttering this mantra, touch heart.
ॐ ॐ बीजाय नमो गुह्ये। - by uttering this mantra, touch lingam.
ॐ नमः शक्तये नमः पादयोः। - by uttering this mantra, touch feet.
ॐ शिवायेति कीलकाय नमो नाभौ। - by uttering this mantra, touch navel.
ॐ विनियोगाय नमः सर्वाङ्गे। - by uttering this mantra, touch entire body.

— इति ऋष्यादिन्यासः। The above 7 steps is known as Rishiyādhi nyāsa
II) Kara Nyāsa (करन्यास) for Sri Shiva Tantra:

ॐ श्रां अङ्गुष्ठाभ्यां नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch thumb from bottom to top by index finger tip (both hands simultaneously).
ॐ नं तर्जनीभ्यां नमः। - by uttering this mantra, touch index finger from bottom to top by thumb tip (both hands simultaneously).
ॐ मं मध्यमाभ्यां नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch middle finger from bottom to top by thumb tip (both hands simultaneously).
ॐ शिं अनामिकाभ्यां नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch ring finger from bottom to top by thumb tip (both hands simultaneously).
ॐ वां कनिष्ठिकाभ्यां नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch little finger from bottom to top by thumb tip (both hands simultaneously).
ॐ यं करतलकरपृष्ठाभ्यां नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch top and bottom of both hands.

— इति करन्यासः। The above 6 steps is known as Kara Nyāsa
III) Hridiyādhi-Shadanga Nyāsa (हृदयादिषडङ्गन्यास) for Sri Shiva Tantra:

ॐ श्रां हृदयाय नमः । - by uttering this mantra, touch heart with right hand ring, middle and index fingers together.
ॐ नं शिरसे स्वाहा। - by uttering this mantra, touch head with right hand ring and middle fingers together.
ॐ मं शिखायै वषट् । - by uttering this mantra, touch hair with right hand thumb.
ॐ शिं कवचाय हुं । - by uttering this mantra, touch left-shoulder with right-hand five fingers together and at the same time touch right-shoulder with left-hand five fingers together.
ॐ वां नेत्रत्रयाय वौषट् । - by uttering this mantra, touch both eyes and middle of eyebrow (Ājñā chakra/आज्ञा चक्र) with right-hand three fingers viz., ring finger (left-eye), middle finger (Ājñā chakra) and index finger (right-eye) simultaneously.
ॐ यं अस्त्राय फट् । - by uttering this mantra, strike left-hand palm with right-hand index and middle fingers together with Finger snap (sound) after circling head with finger snap. Note: Twice finger snap (sound) should be made, first time while circling head clockwise and second while striking both the fingers with left-hand palm.

— इति हृदयादिषडङ्गन्यासः। The above 6 steps is known as Hridiyadhi Nyāsa or Anga Nyāsa or Shadanga Nyasa.

What a beautiful answer, can you try to answer this?


Any mantra needs initiation(otherwise not effective/might not give siddhi).
Guru will reach an aspirant when time is ripe. If we become desperate we will get frauds and imposter.
For simple folks like us

take any favourite deity and just chant his/her name/stotram/slokas.
read scriptures/religious books.



I believe, when hunger is there divine mother will guide us slowly.

Om namah shivai is a nama mantra and it can be chanted by anyone . Vedic mantras and tantric Beeja mantras require initiation. Also some stotras like Lalita Sahasranama also require initiation

Well said, @Sillyasker, I see reference of Shiva Puran as well by others. I will read some good text on mantra shastra. As you said exceptions are there ; we should not generalise.
